# Declare EventHandlers as Static or Non-Static in WPF Controls

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, binding

I was working on creating a custom control with Command behavior and came across something odd. Some articles I found declared the CanExecuteChangedHandler EventHandler as static and others were non-static. Microsoft's SDK documentation shows static but when I declare it as static I get odd behavior when using multiple controls.

```
private static EventHandler canExecuteChangedHandler;

private void AddSecureCommand(ISecureCommand secureCommand)
{
    canExecuteChangedHandler = new EventHandler(CanExecuteChanged);
    securityTypeChangedHandler = new EventHandler(SecurityTypeChanged);

    if (secureCommand != null)
    {
        secureCommand.CanExecuteChanged += canExecuteChangedHandler;
        secureCommand.SecurityTypeChanged += securityTypeChangedHandler;
    }
}
```

Does anyone know the proper way? Am I doing something wrong that is causing the static EventHandler not to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stated reason for keeping a local copy of `EventHandler` is that the WPF commanding sub-system uses weak references internally and therefore we need to keep a reference to the specific delegate object that is added to the `CanExecuteChanged` event.  If fact, anytime we are adding to any commanding sub-system event, we should also observe this practice, as you have for `SecurityTypeChanged`.

The short answer to your question is that `canExecuteChangedHandler` **can** be static, but you must be careful to only **initialize it once**.  The reason it can be static is that all `new EventHandler(CanExecuteChanged)` will do the same thing if `CanExecuteChanged` is static.  The reason to initialize it once is that different instances are different.

A private property that has the right read-only semantics is:

```
static EventHandler canExecuteChangedHandler
{
    get
    {
        if (internalCanExecuteChangedHandler == null)
            internalCanExecuteChangedHandler = new EventHandler(CanExecuteChanged);
        return internalCanExecuteChangedHandler;
    }

}
static EventHandler internalCanExecuteChangedHandler;
```

but this only works if `CanExecuteChanged` is static.  If it is not, then remove the `static` qualifiers.  In either case you have to be careful to actually **use** the property.

In this particular example, the second time that `AddSecureCommand` is called the first `canExecuteChangedHandler` is at risk of being garbage collected.

Finally, if this all sounds like black-magic, here is a code example to show what is happening.

```
public class Container
{
    private WeakReference reference;
    public object Object
    {
        get { return reference.IsAlive ? reference.Target : null; }
        set { reference = new WeakReference(value); }
    }
}

public class DelegateTest
{
    private EventHandler eventHandler;
    private Container container1;
    private Container container2;

    void MyEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
    }

    public DelegateTest()
    {
        this.eventHandler = new EventHandler(MyEventHandler);
        this.container1 = new Container { Object = this.eventHandler };
        this.container2 = new Container { Object = new EventHandler(MyEventHandler) };
        GC.Collect();
        Console.WriteLine("container1: {0}", this.container1.Object == null);
        Console.WriteLine("container2: {0}", this.container2.Object == null);
    }
}
```

This produces this output:

```
container1: False
container2: True
```

which indicates that during the garbage collection that the second container had its `EventHandler` garbage-collected "out from underneath it".  This is by design the way that weak references work and the explanation for you need to keep a reference to it yourself.

Comment: I understand the garbage collection reason and I know I have to have the EventHandler declared at the class level. The problem I am having is when I instantiate the class multiple times I get odd behavior when it is static.

Comment: I meant to add a newline and it submitted the comment. I tried to edit the above comment but apparently I only get 5 minutes to update it. To elaborate above... The problem I am having is when I instantiate the class (or control) multiple times I get odd behavior when it is static. After doing a little more research I see that the EventHandler delegate's target is specific to the instance. In my case using a static EventHandler is causing issues. I can see how there might be times when a static EventHandler could be used but I guess it will not work in my case.

Comment: To summarize your point: the event handler reference can be static only when the method is static.  You still have to be careful not to modify it after you've added it to commanding events.  I'll update the answer.

Comment: To comment on the garbage collection, if I do not create the EventHandler as static then one instance will be created per class instance and this will also prevent garbage collection. Thanks for all the information.